# @nrwl NX error on generating nest library NX 'project.json' files are incompatible with version 1 workspace schemas

Tags: angular, nest, nrwl-nx

Recently updated nx and angular using Nx migration steps. Ever since almost everything is broken in the repository.

I am getting this error on running @nrwl/nest library generator command.  I can't figure out the issue. Plz help..

```
 >  NX   'project.json' files are incompatible with version 1 workspace schemas.


Error: 'project.json' files are incompatible with version 1 workspace schemas.
    at D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\nx\src\config\workspaces.js:322:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at toOldFormatOrNull (D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\nx\src\config\workspaces.js:320:37)
    at reformattedWorkspaceJsonOrNull (D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\nx\src\config\workspaces.js:277:68)
    at addProjectToWorkspaceJson (D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\nx\src\generators\utils\project-configuration.js:248:112)
    at setProjectConfiguration (D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\nx\src\generators\utils\project-configuration.js:205:5)
    at addProjectConfiguration (D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\nx\src\generators\utils\project-configuration.js:22:5)
    at addProject (D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\@nrwl\js\src\generators\library\library.js:87:46)
    at D:\projects\jafar-tech\node_modules\@nrwl\js\src\generators\library\library.js:26:9
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: If you have an angular.json file, set the version from 1 to 2. This should fix your issue

Comment: the issue change to Invalid format version detected - Expected:[ 1 ] Found: [ 2 ]

Comment: @MehradRafigh that doesn't solve the issue, now adding libraries through the nx cli creates empty libraries on the angular.json file.